# Can you display an audio player and a pdf file inline in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift

I was able to display an image inline in a UITextView using the following code:

```
    let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    textAttachment.image = sentImage
    let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
    textView.textStorage.insert(attrStringWithImage, at: textView.selectedRange.location)
```

Is there a similar way that I can display an audio player and a pdf file inline in a UITextView?

Comment: What does "display an audio recording" mean here? It's an audio recording, not an image. Unless of course you somehow turn it into an image.

Comment: Edited question! I want to display an audio player inline that will play an audio recording.

Comment: OK then the answer is no. What you are describing sounds like a job for a web view. But you can make your image clickable and respond to the click by playing music or something; in other words, your image can act like a link, if that would be sufficient.